# Can't resize DropdownButtonFormField without breaking a Text

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying resize DropdownButtonFormField with SizedBox. The Hinttext is shown correctly, but when I choose on of the options I get a half of text.

Also I have the Column with TextFields and SizedBox (for separating them) and I want have

What I have

[image]

What I want but with correct Text not only hint

[image]

```
return SizedBox(height: 42.5, child: DropdownButtonFormField(
      value: _selectedVal,
      items: _items
          .map((x) => DropdownMenuItem(
                value: x,
                child: Text(x),
              ))
          .toList(),
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedVal = val as String;
        });
      },
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        hintText: 'hintText',
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: seems it is covered by underline[arrow height]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add contentPadding  EdgeInsets.zero inside InputDecoration

```
return SizedBox(height: 42.5, child: DropdownButtonFormField(
  value: _selectedVal,
  items: _items
      .map((x) => DropdownMenuItem(
            value: x,
            child: Text(x),
          ))
      .toList(),
  onChanged: (val) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedVal = val as String;
    });
  },
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero          <====== Here
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.white,
    hintText: 'hintText',
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
    ),
  ),
));
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks better if we add padding on the left